# Implement full HTML page caching on CDN

Tags: kentico

We are trying to implement a full page html caching using CDN on our Kentico portal engine site. To be able to do this we need to set the cache-control of the documents and not only assets to "public". I've tried adding the code below in my global.asax begin request event to test it but for some reason the document response header cache-control is always set to no-cache. Did Kentico intentionally set it? I would think yes because they have its own caching mechanism built-in but if we want to use CDN we need to set the cache to public. Is there a way to override this?

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
```

I also tried modifying the PortalTemplate.aspx.cs to add cache-control meta tag but it also did not work.

```
  tags.Text += "<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"public\" />";
```

The response header is always

> cache-control:no-cache, must-revalidate
>   content-encoding:deflate
>   content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
>   date:Fri, 02 Mar 2018 18:38:03 GMT
>   expires:-1
>   pragma:no-cache
>   server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>   status:200
>   vary:Accept-Encoding
>   x-aspnet-version:4.0.30319
>   x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
>   x-powered-by:ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to override it in PreSendRequestHeaders event in global.asax.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object source, EventArgs e)
{        
     //removed some code for brevity
     var headers = Response.Headers;
     headers.Remove("cache-control");
     headers.Remove("pragma");
     headers.Remove("expires");
     headers.Remove("set-cookie");
     headers.Add("cache-control", "public, max-age=" + TimeSpan.FromHours(1).TotalSeconds.ToString());            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding in a great article for static sites by one of the MVPs

https://www.kenticotricks.com/blog/static-sites-with-kentico-cloud